# The confusion about * {margin:0; padding:0;}

Tags: css, padding, margin, css-reset

In some articles that I've read, the use of `* {margin:0; padding:0;}` is discouraged as it would affect the web site's performance. So I turned to a `reset.css` stylesheet.

But I'm wondering, how does it affect the performance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reasoning behind this was discussed in [this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/04/18/reset-reasoning/) Eric Meyer post.

> This is why so many people zero out
>   their padding and margins on
>   everything by way of the universal
>   selector. That’s a good start, but it
>   does unfortunately mean that all
>   elements will have their padding and
>   margin zeroed, including form elements
>   like textareas and text inputs. In
>   some browsers, these styles will be
>   ignored. In others, there will be no
>   apparent effect. Still others might
>   have the look of their inputs altered.
>   Unfortunately, there’s just no way to
>   know, and it’s an area where things
>   are likely to change quite a bit over
>   the next few years.
>
> So that’s why I don’t want to use the
>   universal selector, but instead
>   explicitly list out elements to be
>   reset. In this way, I don’t have to
>   worry about munging form elements. (I
>   really should write about the
>   weirdnesses inherent in form elements,
>   but that’s for another day.)

That said, the following chart from [this](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/06/18/simplifying-css-selectors/) Steve Souders post shows the difference in load times for a test page using [universal selectors](http://stevesouders.com/efws/css-selectors/universal.php) compared with a page using [descendant selectors](http://stevesouders.com/efws/css-selectors/descendant.php).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

it is effect the performance because the browsers engine have to apply this style to every element on the page this will lead to heavy rendering specially in the big pages with a lot of elements and this method is a bad practice too because it may remove a good default styles for some elements

you may optimize this code by reduce the scope of it like using it on just some elements that make the problems like this

`h1,ul
    { 
margin:0;`
`padding:0;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Using `*{margin:0;padding:0;}` in your `stylesheet` will not affect performance and is helpful in tackling various formatting issues.

Using a separate `reset.css` does have some performance issues, as you are forcing the user to requested one more file from the server.  In the grand scheme of things, a few kb on a high speed line is nothing.  But another file for someone on a mobile browser can be too much.

Answer (score 0):

I think the website you read that on needs its head checked, a reset style sheet is the way to go to level the playing field. The overhead is so marginal it won't make a difference especially with modern browsers.

Answer (score -1):

```
body {padding:0;margin:0;}
```

It effects the webpage display because without its use we have to

```
margin-left:-7px;
margin-top:-7px;
```

etc. like substitutions to avoid a narrow white strip on the left and top of the webpage.